# applying the same .click event to two different divs

Tags: jquery, click

i have two different divs (code was simplified, this is not the actual code.)

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="funt"></div>
```

what i want is, to attach the same click event to `#funt`:
something like:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    DoWork();
});
$('#funt).click(function() {
    DoWork();
});

function DoWork(){
    alert('yes');
}
```

but isn't there a way to define multiple div's the same click event?

lets say ( yes, i know this does not work! )

`($('#test'),('#funt')).click(function(){alert('yes')});`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply:

```
$("#test, #funt").click(DoWork);
```

See [Multiple Selector.](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
($('#test','#funt')).click(function(){alert('yes')});
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to your div's, and then assign the click event using the class like this:

```
<div class="clickable" id="test"></div>
<div class="clickable" id="funt"></div>
```

Then

```
$('.clickable').click(function()
{
    DoWork();
});
```

You could also list the id's like this:

```
$("#test, #funt").click(DoWork);
```

I usually try to use classes because it's cleaner when you're dealing with multiple divs - you don't have to list the ID of each.

Comment: you have to understand that sometimes it is not possible to make changes to code. recommendation of adding/removing classes is usually good for a new started site, not for a site with over 6000 pages.

Comment: @Dementic, You should understand that without that type of information being in the original question, you'll get answers like mine. Please note, I presented two options, one where a markup change was required, and one where it was not. Based on your original question (that contained no information about not changing the markup), I think this was a good approach :)

Comment: i didnt ment any harm... english is not my native language, and im sorry if sometimes i sound harsh ;). but i really think that as a programmer, you should allways first consider options with no markup change, and only if it is not possible, consider other options.

Comment: @Dementic, no offense taken. My response was simply an encouragment to put more information in your original question (and an attempt to get an up-vote).

Answer (score 0):

You were actually pretty close:

```
 $('#test, #funt').click(function() {
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either you could give both of those divs a class and then just run the code:

```
$(".myclass").click(function() {
    DoWork();
});
```

Or you could define a function like:

```
function hookClick(arr, handler)  {
    foreach (var i in arr) {
        $(i).click(handler);
    }
}
```

then run it using

```
hookClick(["#div1", "#div2"], function() { /*do sth cool })
```

Comment: nice idea, but too complicated. i am looking for a solution like karmi79's.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax to do so,

When working with **`Classes`**

```
$(".className1, .className2, .classNameN").on('click', function(){
    Do_Some_Work();
});
```

When working with **`Id's`**

```
$("#ID1, #ID2, #IDN").on('click', function(){
    Do_Some_Work();
});
```

When working with **Combination** of `ID` and `Class`

```
<div id="z">z
    <div class="w">w</div>
    <div class="x">x</div>
   <div class="y">y</div>
</div>

$('#z.w , #z.y').on('click', function(){
    Do_Some_Work();
    //Pointer come here only when it click on `W` and `Y`
});
```