# How to make two div clickable by using one click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div and I want to open these two div in new tab by using one click.

```
<a href="http://google.com"><div id="google">This is Google.</div></a>
<a href="http://youtube.com"><div id="youtube">This is YouTube.</div></a>
```

Comment: but browsers not support these type of action, it open 1 tab and says popup block for another tab<a onclick="window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9eyRLUsgLk');
            window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79fk_2c2pA8');
            window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QI8qUazpBNY')
href="http://taglinefor.blogspot.in/" target="_blank">click fast to show results </a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open link in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551779/open-link-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do that

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').each(function() {
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
    });
});
```

---

Here's a [**demonstration**](https://jsfiddle.net/1zao6e10/) using a button

Comment: Would you not want to preventDefault as well?

Comment: @rPat - sure, sounds like a good idea to avoid one of them twice.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'target=_blank'` to in `<a>` tag .

```
    <a href="http://google.com" target='_blank'><div id="google">This is Google.</div></a>
    <a href="http://youtube.com" target='_blank'><div id="youtube">This is YouTube.</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for both

```
<script>
  $('#googel,#youtube').click(function()
  {
     // your commands...
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript, it's not possible to open two links in two different tabs on one click. So my suggestion is to wrap those divs in a parent div and do some javascript.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.onclick = function(){
  window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
  window.open('http://youtube.com', '_blank');
};
```

```css
#wrapper{
  cursor: pointer;
}

#wrapper:hover{
  background-color: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="google">This is Google.</div> 
  <div id="youtube">This is YouTube.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can try this:

```
$("#google, #youtube").click("Do your work");
```

For more:
[Reference-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732473/applying-the-same-click-event-to-two-diffrent-divs) & [Reference-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926207/how-to-open-different-divs-by-clicking-on-a-single-button)